# Natural English language words

Tags: nlp

I need the most exhaustive English word list I can find for several types of language processing operations, but I could not find anything on the internet that has good enough quality.

There are 1,000,000 words in the English language including foreign and/or technical words.

Can you please suggest such a source (or close to 500k words) that can be downloaded from the internet that is maybe a bit categorized? What input do you use for your language processing applications?

Comment: If your dictionary has 1 million words, you can bet that misspellings of common words are going to be mistaken for some obscure 1-in-a-million word. That could affect the usefulness of such a large dictionary.

Comment: @Germstorm: where did you get this 1 million number?  Do you have a specific reference, or is this rumor?

Comment: I just heard it somewhere, I cannot validate it

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Kevin's wordlists](http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/) is the best I know just for lists of words.

[WordNet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/) is better if you want to know about things being nouns, verbs etc, synonyms, etc.

Comment: I've used Kevin's lists before. I merged a bunch of them together to get one huge list so I could generate all possible words from a given set of chars.

Comment: @dotjoe they have a nice [web interface](http://app.aspell.net/create) now that will do that for you (:

Answer (score 8):

`[The "million word" hoax rolls along](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=972)', I see ;-)

How to make your word lists longer: given a noun, add any of the following to it: non-, pseudo-, semi-, -arific, -geek, ...; [mutatis mutandis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutatis_mutandis) for verbs etc.

Answer (score 4):

I did research for Purdue on controlled / natural english and language domain knowledge processing.

I would take a look at the attempto project: http://attempto.ifi.uzh.ch/site/description/ which is a project to help build a controlled natural english.

You can download their entire word lexicon at: http://attempto.ifi.uzh.ch/site/downloads/files/clex-6.0-080806.zip it has ~ 100,000 natural English words.

You can also supply your own lexicon for domain specific words, this is what we did in our research. They offer webservices to parse and format natural english text.

Answer (score 3):

Who told you there was 1 million words?  According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_language#Number_of_words_in_English), the Oxford English Dictionary only has 600,000.  And the OED tries to include all technical and slang terms that are used.

Comment: What's a power of two between friends?

Comment: English is a synthetic language.  I've heard the 1M number too, usually as a lower bound on the number of words that you can create on the fly.

Answer (score 2):

Try directly Wikipedia's extracts : http://dbpedia.org

Answer (score 0):

There aren't too many base words(171k according to this- [oxford](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/words/how-many-words-are-there-in-the-english-language). Which is what I remember being told in my CS program in college. 
But if include all forms of the words- then it rises considerably.

That said, why not make one yourself? Get a Wikipedia dump and parse it and create a set of all tokens you encounter.

Expect misspellings though- like all things crowd-sources there will be errors.