# Dictionary words for download

Tags: nlp, document-classification

Can someone offer a suggestion on where to find a dictionary word list with frequency information?

Ideally, the source would be English words of the North American variety.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Natural English language words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/450493/natural-english-language-words)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [this](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aFrequency_lists)?

Comment: You could use Google Refine (http://code.google.com/p/google-refine/) to extract the data like they do in this tutorial video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45EnWK-fE9k.

Answer (score 3):

Try Kevin's Word List.

http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/

It's opensource, plain text and has many dictionaries.

Answer (score 3):

Check the following link, contains unigrams/bigrams/trigrams corpus

http://blog.afterthedeadline.com/2010/07/20/after-the-deadline-bigram-corpus-our-gift-to-you/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about frequency information but the [Open Office dictionaries](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries) would be a good place to look for LGPL word lists.