# Java: How to Recognize "Real" Words

Tags: java, nlp

I'm developing a program which receives blocks of text. The text may be split between words or in the middle of a word -- there is no way to be sure. I'd like to discard the partial words, whether at the beginning or end. Is there a program/API out there that can help to identify legitimate words? Obviously, there will be some issues, with proper names, compound words, etc. Thanks!

Comment: @Baz - sure, works for me. i'll up your karma. :-)

Comment: Cheers :) Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are searching for something like an English dictionary? Then: [How to implement an English dictionary in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986543/how-to-implement-an-english-dictionary-in-java) should help you. [Natural English language words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/450493/natural-english-language-words?rq=1) might also be interesting.

Basically, they are parsing a long list of all (or most) words in the English language and checking if a specific word is contained.